# Is there a way to convert expressions to mathematical environments on-the-fly?

Tags: parsing, latex, mathjax

For instance, if I was to type the expression `a/b` in a compatible application like Microsoft Word, it will be parsed and rendered automatically into the expression $$\frac{a}{b}$$. Similarly, a complex expression like `1+(a/(a+b))` is converted into the expression $$1+\frac{a}{a+b}$$.

No extra `Insert -> Object -> Equation Editor` nor `Services -> Typeset` needed.

Comment: You mean the TeX compiler? Or you mean TeX just with your preferred syntax (say, `a/b`) instead of the syntax there is already (`$$\frac{a}{b}$$`)??

Comment: This sounds annoying. Sometimes a slash is just a slash.

Comment: @Mr.F StackOverflow can't render TeX to images.